# QtCreator wizard: Set folder name of the project folder

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In QtCreator you can create custom wizards that will create new projects or classes. These wizards specify customizable parameters that are able to modify skeleton templates.

When creating new projects with a custom wizards, is there any way to specify the base folder name of the project?

Let's take the following wizard as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wizard version="1" kind="project"
        class="qmakeproject" firstpage="10"
        id="A.Node" category="B.Framework">
    <icon>console.png</icon>
    <description>Create a new Node</description>
    <displayname>Node</displayname>;
    <displaycategory>Framework</displaycategory>
    <files>
        <file source="skeleton.cpp" 
         target="%ProjectName:l%node.cpp" openeditor="true"/>
        <file source="skeleton.h" 
         target="%ProjectName:l%node.h" openeditor="true"/>
        <file source="skeleton.pro.ske" 
         target="%ProjectName:l%node.pro" openproject="false"/>
    </files>
</wizard>
```

This wizard takes thee files (skeleton.pro, skeleton.cpp and skeleton.h), modifies the contents of the files, and changes the name of the files to the name of the project (lower case) plus the word "node" at the end.

These files are all placed in a folder named after the project name (the special variable %ProjectName%). **Is there a way to specify that the base folder of the project should also have the word "node" appended to it?**

If I choose to name the project "algorithm", for instance, the desired folder name would be "algorithmnode" such that the folder structure would look like:

```
algorithmnode/
    algorithmnode.pro
    algorithmnode.h
    algorithmnode.cpp
```

However, the base folder is by default the name of the project.

Comment: Are you talking about Qt Creator?

Comment: It is about QT Creator, indeed. Question edited.